# How can i implement Plivo 2 way SMS for ios application?

Tags: ios, swift, sms, plivo

I want to do like Uber for communication between driver and user. How can i get the numbers of sender and receiver and how will i bind the numbers with plivo number. I am not able to check the 2 way SMS in the docs. I have trial account and i would like to make a proof of concept(POC). Please provide me the links from where i could start making POC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plivo Sales engineer here.

To do what you describe, you need to set up a server to interact with your iOS app. A user of your iOS app will make a request to your server to send the driver a message and your server will send the SMS to the driver. Then when the driver responds via SMS your server will send a notification to your app on the user's phone. See https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/send-a-single-sms/ for an example of how to send an SMS.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned about the SMS i don't want any information regarding calls.

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the answer to reflect sms usage